# Configuration Management Settings doesn't work in other computers

Tags: c#

I change settings of connection string in project like this:

```
        var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[2];
        var fi = typeof(ConfigurationElement).GetField("_bReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        fi.SetValue(settings, false);
       // settings.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=XXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=InsuranceDB;Data Source=ERNA2";
        //settings.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database\InSuranceDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=XXX";
        int onlineMode = int.Parse(File.ReadAllText("onlineMode.obj"));
        if (onlineMode==1)
        {
            settings.ConnectionString = @"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=XXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=InsuranceDB;Data Source=TABARI\SAMA2008";
           // settings.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database\InSuranceDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=XXX";
        }
        else
        {
            settings.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database\InSuranceDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=XXX!";
        }
        File.WriteAllText("onlineMode.obj", "1");
```

It work nice in my computer but after publish it doesn't work and application read data from app.config. Could you please help me to solve this?
Also I remove condition but not solve problem :(

Comment: Btw. thanks for all the passwords!

Comment: @OndrejTucny It's not important. Because we will change it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the user running the app doesn't have permission to modify the config file in the deployment location.

In any case, why are you reading from another file (`"onlineMode.obj"`) to get a configuration setting?  Seems like a safer way is to have *both* of your connection strings and `onlineMode` in your config file, then select the appropriate connection string in your application.

And what's the point of *writing* the connection string to your config file if you're just overwriting it with a hard-coded value in code?

Comment: because .net have bug when try to read online mode from settings. When I use if he do condition but not apply correctly. I don't know why. After I use onlineMode.obj it work correctly in my pc. But after publish doesn't work any thing in another computers. Also I run application in administrator mode and remove conditions but doen't work after that.

Comment: ".net has a bug" can you be more specific?

Comment: @D Stanley: In debug mode every thing work true. Conditions check and connection setting change. But application couldn't connect to server when use Settings Variable. But when use onlineMode.obj It have same behavior but application can connect to server. In debug mode to method works same but in real objectModel.obj change connection string.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is but I doubt it's a .NET bug.  What you're trying to do is a common scenario and should be possible with just config settings.  I'd suggest asking another question to solve the problem reading from config settings.